# How do I apply login_required() in django?

Tags: mysql, django, authentication

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from views import PostListView
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^test/$', PostListView.as_view(), name='test'),
)
```

When I do this its as if Django completely ignores the login_required and goes straight to the template. I have authentication correctly setup. I can register new accounts into the MySQL database and login/authenticate successfully. Right now I just want to restrict some pages to registered users only. and have it basically stay logged in when you login. Like an actual site.

Edit:

`views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, get_object_or_404, render, render_to_response
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.views.generic.base import View, TemplateView
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from models import *
from forms import *
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    context_object_name = "post_list"

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(PostListView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_template_names(self):
        return ["app/list.html"]

    def get_queryset(self):
        posts = Post.objects
        if 'all_posts' not in self.request.GET:
            posts = posts.filter(is_published=True)                                                         
        return posts
```

Comment: how can you import `from django.views import view` if that view doesn't exist??

Comment: @ruddra I meant myproject.views

Comment: Please post the full traceback when you use `login_required(PostListView.as_view()` in your view -- that approach should work.

Comment: @Alasdair The debug page doesn't come up. Is there another way to force a traceback page? Even if Django is not recognizing any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just subclass the View and use like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
class PostListView(ListView):
      @method_decorator(login_required)
      def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
            return super(PostListView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

urls should be;

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^test/$', PostListView.as_view(), name='test'),
)
```

Comment: It says 'View' object has no attribute 'user'

Comment: please paste your view

Comment: Updated original post with the `views.py` file.

Comment: I forgot to mention that you have to change your urls too. updated my answer. plz check it @spvceman

Comment: Still same issue as adding 'login_required()' in urls.py directly. It doesn't want to recognize authorization.

Comment: ok, if I have updated my answer again :| and remove the code of `get` from your view. if error still occurs then I have to request you to give your error traceback. @spvceman

Comment: I am not entirely sure how to debug that method. or force a traceback specifically in that area. I'll figure it out and get back to you.

Comment: I think I am having an idea why your authorization is being ignored. Clear your cache from browser and reload the project, see what happens @spvceman :)

Comment: And man, you are correct. Don't you hate it when at the end of the day after so many hours it turns out to be cache. Thank you ruddra. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer it this way, puttin the decorator in the url

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from app.views import MyView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^app/url/action/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', login_required(MyView.as_view()),
    name='my_view_action'),
)
```

Comment: `(?P<pk>\d+)/$` is this portion only good for added security?

Comment: Just an example with parameter